# Save Special Character into Database

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I am currently using html and php for my site but I have this problem while saving in textarea.

Everytime I use a different font with special character like ' and " it saves like â�� (a black diamond with question mark inside). This usually happens when I copy a text from other site or when I copy a text document then paste it but when I type in the textarea it works fine.

sample:

> donâ��t take no for an answer and are individuals who care about

Here is my html code

```
    <form action="savepost.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset style="width:600px; height:580px">
    <br><strong>Title</strong> <input id="posttitle" name="posttitle" type="text">
    <br><br><strong>Content</strong>
    <br><textarea id="postform" name="postform" style="width:600px; height:450px; resize: none"></textarea>
    <br><input type="submit" value="Post" id="postbutton"/>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Mysql Insert

```
    $title = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['posttitle']));
    $post_title = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','', $title);
    $timestamp=time(); 
    $post = $_POST['postform'];

    $newtitle= preg_replace('/\\s+/', ' ',$post_title);
    $striptitle = trim($newtitle, ' ');
    $url = strtolower($timestamp.'/'.str_replace(" ", "-", $striptitle));

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO blog (title, url, timestamp, post) VALUES ('$title', '$url', '$timestamp', '$post')");
```

what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

This is an character encoding issue - if you are copying the content from a desktop program (MS Word) then Word puts in the angled quote not a straight quote, but if the HTML page is not in the correct encoding to display that character it will show like above.

try looking in the header of your page for

`<meta charset="utf-8" />`

or something similar

if it is not `utf-8` or missing try changing it and see what happens.

Comment: Sir, I already have the code <meta charset="utf-8" /> in my code but doesn't work. Does it has to do with the data type in mysql?

Comment: You didn't mention that you were putting in a database - yes check the database character set as well as the column character set

Comment: Sir, I just set the collation to utf8_unicode_ci and used <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Checking if it works.

Comment: can you edit your question and add the lines of code that you are using to save to the database as well as the `CREATE TABLE` definition for the table you are using?

Comment: I'm referring to the lines of php code that call the `UPDATE` to save this text field in the database

Comment: can you also add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE blog` results?

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying some of this text from Microsoft Word?  By default, Word will change your regular "straight" quotes into "curly" quotes.  There's a way to [turn this feature off](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-curly-quotes-to-straight-quotes-and-vice-versa-HP005190124.aspx).  To fix the text you have, you might have to do a find/replace.

Comment: Sir, I don't think that it has to do with word features. I think the problem is with my coding but I can't figure it out yet.